# Flutter project, Android folder seems to have been excluded

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, flutter

I have an existing flutter app.  I cannot see the android folder in the project.  It is there in the directory and in Git.  One of the problems is that when I commit my changes through the built in version control, Idea does not see my changes and does not commit them.

How do I include the android folder?

*I am quite new to Idea*

Comment: Check that the project root directory is correct in File | Project Structure | Modules | <module name> -> **Sources** tab. Also check which [view](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/project-tool-window.html#views) is selected in Project tool window. Set it to 'Project' if it is different.

Comment: Hi @Andrey, yes the root directory is correct and the Project tool window is Project.  I think I may have added some excluded folders somewhere.  I didn't want the android folders cluttering my project window so I may have specifically excluded it sometime but I don't know where (I didn't know it would affect the git checkin)

Comment: not to worry, I had put an entry in 'ignore files and folders' option in settings